# What is the increase of surface area and volume of this sphere?

Tags: volume, surfaces

A sphere with $r$ is doubling and its radius is being $2r$.

- What is the increase of surface area $\pi r^2$?
- What is the increase of its volume $\pi r^3$?

I know that

$$A = 4\pi r^2$$

And for volume

$$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$$

I'm getting wrong when I try to calculate.

Comment: What about taking a break and trying to do it yourself? You really have too many questions about this topic.

Comment: @ThePirateBay This topic seems too hard. I'm already doing myself but sometimes I'm stuck.

Comment: What is the "radius" of a cube? Why are you using the formula for sphere surface area and volume for the cube?

Comment: Subtract A final from A initial and same for Volume.

Comment: Would it be $4\pi r^2 = 4\pi2^2$?

Comment: @Lagranian. It is ok to get stuck sometimes, but keep in mind that if you continue posting low-quality questions, you may be suspended from asking in the future.

Comment: @ThePirateBay I'm too sorry but I really don't get problems like these. I will do it next time.

Comment: If anyone can take a look ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting area of sphere is $A_1= 4\pi r^2.$ After doubling the radius, the new area is $A_2= 4\pi \,(2r)^2=16\pi r^2=4 \times A_1.$ So the new area is $4$ times the old area.

This will solve your doubt. Just see it and same can be done for volume.

Comment: Did you understood this

Comment: Can you please learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? It isn't so scary, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant a sphere. For your question:
If radius of sphere is $7cm$ then it's area is $4\pi r^2 = 616$
Calculating with new radius we get answer as $2464$ which is $4$ times of previous one hence if radius is doubled then it's total surface area becomes $4$ times actual one
Similarly, in the case of volume it becomes $8$ times as original.

Comment: Yes, I meant sphere and it seems wrong. the radius of sphere is $2r$.

Comment: Did it helped you

Comment: Currently, It didn't.

Comment: Now I will explain you better

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: and radius is $2r$, not $7$.

Comment: Or else it will send a image

Comment: Edit it, I'm holding on.

Comment: It seems wrong. According to my textbook, It's $12\pi r^2$.

Comment: Answer in your textbook should be weong